# Autocomplete for the text field in the zend form - Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

Following the Album Module from Zend Framework 2 official site, I am planning to add the auto-complete function, for example in the Artist text field, I want to include the auto complete function such that when the user types in, I want to show a drop down list populated with the data similar to the one which the user is typing, so what is the best way to approach this problem. On searching the Zend Frame 2 site I have landed on this [page](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formelement).

I am not sure whether my approach is right approach or not, any guidance to proceed in the right way would be appreciated. Any example regarding this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going for Auto-Suggest today, you should ask yourself a single question:

**How much data is the maximum for auto-suggest**

Reasoning:

If the data is only few, i.e. if you have a list of Car-Vendors or something alike. Or futher, if you have a very limited amount of entries, then you should consider going the HTML5-way using [DATALIST](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_datalist.asp)

However, if the data changes often, and is quite big, then loading everything upfront is not the most ideal way and going for AJAX is the right thing to do. Nothing ZF2-Specific in here :)

Answer (score 0):

you should start learning ajax if you dont know what ajax is.. once you figure out how to do ajax then if you find some trouble then you can come here for some code suggestion but try yourself first

Comment: i have been already familiar with Ajax, I wanted to know the right approach to do it using Zend Framework 2